# Password protected MP3 file

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have to create a simple system to protect an MP3 file with PHP. I'll have an `index.php` page that will have a single password input. The form will target `download.php`. This file will check if the password/key matches and download an MP3 file that can only be downloaded once. (I'll have multiple passwords in a database that will be erased after the downloaded).

I'd like to know how to protect this file or generate it only when `download.php` is opened.

Comment: This is an open-ended question not specific enough to answer on this site.  You're basically asking how to build something from scratch, instead of asking about a specific issue you are facing.  There are plenty of online resources that will explain how to read database values using PHP.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I know exactly how to read database values, my question is specific. I want to protect an MP3 file using PHP.

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to link you to tutorials or explain concepts. You're supposed to post some code, tell us why it's not working, and then we help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Store the file anywhere on the server, just not in `public_html` or any folder therein (or whatever your document root is). That way, there's no way for anyone to access the file just by looking up its URL. The PHP on the server, however, can easily access the file.

Comment: If you only have access to `public_html` deny access via `.htacess` via `RewriteRule ^path/to/my/file\.mp3$ - [F]` (assuming Apache)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the file outside of the document root, and then programmatically create a symlink to it from your doc root. This has the advantage that you can let Apache serve the file, rather than requiring PHP to do it - which keeps your memory requirements lower.

For example, let's say your project is here:

```
/var/www/music-app
```

And your docroot is here:

```
/var/www/music-app/www
```

Store your music file here:

```
/var/www/music-app/files/myfile.mp3
```

And then create this symlink that you offer to authenticated users, which links to the MP3 file:

```
/var/www/music-app/www/links/hf6g298g2gng2kg2ug29g2j2gmg.mp3
```

You can then use a cron job to tidy up dead links that are older than, say, a week.